# Why one code faces time complexity issue and the other does not

Tags: java, performance

I was solving the Longest Common Prefix on LeetCode. However, my first solution was facing time complexity problems, and my second code passed. What I cannot understand is there is hardly any difference between the two and codes the time complexity for charAt() is O(1).

I have pasted the respective codes below. What might the problem be?

```
        boolean t = true;
        int j=0;
        
        while (t)
        {            
            for (int i=0; i<strs.length-1; ++i)
            {
                if (j==strs[i].length() || j==strs[i+1].length() || strs[i].charAt(j) != strs[i+1].charAt(j))
                {
                    t=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            ++j;
        }
        
        if (j==1)
        {
            return "";
        }
        
        return strs[0].substring(0,j-1);

----------------------------------------------------------------

        boolean t = true;
        int j=0;
        char c;
        
        while (t)
        {
            if (strs[0].length()==0)
            {
                return "";    
            }
            
            if (j>=strs[0].length())
            {
                return strs[0].substring(0,j);
            }
            c=strs[0].charAt(j);
            
            for (int i=0; i<strs.length; ++i)
            {
                if (j==strs[i].length() || strs[i].charAt(j) != c)
                {
                    t=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            ++j;
        }
        
        if (j==1)
        {
            return "";
        }
        
        return strs[0].substring(0,j-1);
```

Comment: "the time complexity for charAt() is O(1)." Okay, but *that isn't actually the part that differs between the two codes*, is it?

Comment: There are 2 charAt in the for loop for the first code however there is only 1 charAt in the for loop for the second code so I thought that could be the difference

Answer (score 0):

Even though the result might come as the same, the running time can vary according to the inputs, because different implementation handles the inputs differently.

What is for certain is that, there are testcase inputs that are taking longer with your first implementation than the second one. The second implementation definitely returns fast for some cases as you have written the if-statements. But to be exact, you will have to time or profile your code to see where the difference occurs exactly.

Comment: This solution doesn't really help you've told me what I already know. What I want to know is the difference in the time complexity both the codes seem similar yet have different time complexities